# Rails how to get the file ending in params? .png, .jpg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having some problem with my image route, because it does not get the image file ending in params.

Here is my route:

```
match '/photographer/image/:id/:filename' => 'application#photore'
```

And my controller:

```
def photore
  redirect_to "http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/photographer/image/#{params[:id]}/#{params[:filename]}"
end
```

I need the filending because else amazon S3 wont load the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aNoble is going in the right direction, the Rails format handling is probably eating the extension but it is also probably throwing it away because it isn't `.html`, `.js`, or any of the other extensions that it understands. Try setting some constraints on the `:filename` in your route:

```
match '/photographer/image/:id/:filename' => 'application#photore', :constraints => { :filename => /.*/ }
```

That should allow the extension to be left as part of `params[:filename]`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're running Rails 3.1, I believe what you're looking for is [`params[:format]`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults). This functionality changed from 3.0 to 3.1 but didn't seem to be very well documented.

Try this:

```
def photore
  redirect_to "http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/photographer/image/#{params[:id]}/#{params[:filename]}.#{params[:format]}"
end
```

Or you should be able to pass [`:format => false`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) to the `match` method and keep your `photore` method the same:

```
match '/photographer/image/:id/:filename' => 'application#photore', :format => false
```

Comment: I am using rails 3.0.9 should my route be: match '/photographer/image/:id/:filename.:format?

Comment: I get No route matches "/photographer/image/55/Sk_rmbillede_2011-08-18_kl._14.34.58.png" is it because of the "." in the time?  in routes I have match '/photographer/image/:id/:filename.:format'

Comment: I believe that `match '/photographer/image/:id/:filename.:extension` and then `params[:extension]` would work. Probably best to avoid using `:format` just to prevent any future conflicts.

Also, you should also be able to do request globbing: `match /photographer/image/:id/*filename` and then just use `params[:filename]` as you were originally.

Comment: Still get a no route matches I have approved Muu answer